# Why sed yields two same line?

Tags: linux, sed

I wanted to replace one line using sed, but got two same lines:

```
$ sed '50s/false/true/p' ./src/com/android/quicksearchbox/SearchableSource.java >SearchableSource.java.1



$ diff SearchableSource.java.1 ./src/com/android/quicksearchbox/SearchableSource.java
50,51c50
<     private static final boolean DBG = true;
<     private static final boolean DBG = true;
---
>     private static final boolean DBG = false;
```

Why? How to do to get I wanted?

Comment: If you only want to replace value of DBG from false to true, it might be better to match it instead of 50th line: `sed '/DBG/ s/false/true/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `p` at the end means "print". You told sed to print the line after successful substitution. Sed prints each line (if not told not to by `-n`) anyway. You have not told us what you wanted, so either remove the final `p` or specify the `-n` option.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the p after the last / ... you're doing a search & replace, and then print the result.

Answer (score 0):

Because the modifier `p` at the end of your command means "print".  The default behavior of `sed` is to print, so you get both.  Use `sed -n` if you want to default to not print, or remove the `p`.